# SQL Server: How should I structure my index to improve lookup time?

Tags: sql-server, database, indexing, database-design, database-optimization

I have a table that stores IP address ranges for a city and there are millions of records in this table. I'm sure that many of you that deal with IP addresses have a similar table to me (I've simplified my table in this example):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IPRangeByCity]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [IPIntegerStart] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [IPIntegerEnd] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Country] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
    [City] [nvarchar](150) NULL

    CONSTRAINT [pk_IPRangeByCity] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([ID] ASC),
) ON [PRIMARY]
 GO
```

Now I don't save, update, or delete any records from this table. I only read from this table. When I read from this table, I take an IPv4 address, convert it to its integer form, and using the integer form of the IPv4 address, I lookup the city between the IP address range for this integer.

For example, let's say the IPv4 address is "187.245.227.116".

"187.245.227.116" converts to the integer 3153453940. Then I run the following select statement to find the city that is associated with this IP address:

```
select * from IPRangeByCity 
where 3153453940 between IPIntegerStart and IPIntegerEnd
```

My question is, if I only ever read from this table with the select statement above, how should I structure my index to improve the lookup time of the select statement?

Off the top of my head, if I set the index for this table to the column "IPIntegerStart", it seems like it may be a good index for my select statement. For example:

```
CONSTRAINT [pk_IPRangeByCity] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([IPIntegerStart] ASC)
```

However, I'm not really sure. Does anybody know what would be the best index to set my for my table, given my select statement? Should it be a clustered or non-clustered index? Should it be a multi column index (ie. an index with both the columns IPIntegerStart and IPIntegerEnd)?  Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: I can make the primary key anything in my table. In this example, I set the primary key to ID, and identity key.  But I can change the primary key to whatever column, as long as my select statement runs fast, that's all I care about.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/14896/3690.

Comment: The improvement is on the grounds that instead of just having a range bounded on one end it is bounded on both ends (except for granule 3 but configure your granule formula so this isn't a large number of rows). If you just have a range bounded on one end such as `IPIntegerStart <= @IpAddressYouAreSearchingFor` and you are searching for a large IP address you still have to process most of the table.

Comment: Hi @Martin, I ran out of space in my last comment.  I have 3 questions:

1) Why are you subtracting 16, 256, etc in the BETWEEN statement:
AND ipFrom BETWEEN somevalue - 16 AND somevalue

2) If my ipto-ipfrom ranges from say, 100 to 2500, should I try to divide the ipto-ipfrom such that 1/3 is mapped to each granule?

3) Does partitioning more for granule lead to a faster seek time?  I see there are 3 granules in the solution.  So if I made 8 granules, would that be even faster?

Thank you.

Comment: It's not my answer. I just edited it to fix some issues in it that I noticed after posting the link. I'd probably try with 3 or 4 equally sized granule groups first and see how performance is for that.

Comment: Thanks @Martin.  Also, I'm still missing the logic regarding the code segment: "AND ipFrom BETWEEN somevalue - 16 AND somevalue AND ipTo >= somevalue".  For example, let's say somevalue = 900, ipFrom = 800, and ipTo = 1000.  If we substitute somevalue = 900, ipFrom = 800, and ipTo = 1000, then the logic becomes "AND 800 BETWEEN (884 AND 900) AND 1000 > 900".   The problem is, 800 isn't between 884 and 900...

Comment: If ipFrom = 800, and ipTo = 1000 then the gap is 200 so that won't be handled by granule 1. That will have a granule of 2 in the answer there. So you need to be looking at `BETWEEN @somevalue - 256 AND @somevalue`

Comment: You can see here it returns the correct results http://rextester.com/SMX43445

Comment: Thanks!  I'll evaluate both your answer and Roger Wolf's answer!

Comment: For the case there's no overlaps the `TOP 1` in that answer and suggested index should work fine and be simpler.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: After a couple of details became known, previous answer doesn't worth anything. It seems that your initial idea might be correct:

```
alter table dbo.IPRangeByCity add constraint [PK_IPRangeByCity]
primary key (IPIntegerStart);
```

However, you will also need a nonclustered index on `IPIntegerEnd`. Below is some explanation.

First, having no overlaps between ranges and the `Id` column being bogus, you can replace your primary key with the one specified. PK is clustered by default, so it will make seeks and scans faster.

Second, as Martin Smith has correctly pointed out in comments, a large index scan will happen with a straightforward query that utilises the `between` predicate or similar logic. However, I think it's not a problem here, because there are no range overlaps, which means that any IP address can belong to at most 1 range. As such, the search query can be rewritten as follows:

```
select top (1) r.*
from dbo.IPRangeByCity r
where 3153453940 between r.IPIntegerStart and r.IPIntegerEnd
order by r.IPIntegerStart desc;
```

This way, it should always be sufficiently fast, because the clustered index scan will stop either after finding the first suitable row, or will be cut off by `IPIntegerEnd`. Note, **this is pure speculation**, you should check it against the amount of data comparable with your production.

Still, I wouldn't discard a denormalising approach similar to that of Jack Douglas (can't say I understood it, though). I wouldn't even discard a possibility of creating a full list of all possible IPv4 addresses and searching through it - it's actually not as ridiculous as it may sound. Ultimately, it all depends on the details.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  There are no overlapping ranges.  Also, I see that your answer suggests using a non-clustered index?  (My understanding is that it defaults to non-clustered if you don't specify the index)

Comment: The problem with this is that it will on average still have to search half the table. The seek is on `IPIntegerStart <=  @IpAddressYouAreSearchingFor` and every matching row needs to be checked to see if it matches the end condition.

Comment: @ProgrammerJoe, I assumed that you can't change the table schema that much, so didn't look into that option. Yes, of course it would be better to have this index clustered - but do you have any other code that expects a quick search on the `Id` column?

Comment: Nope, that ID column isn't used.  It's just an identity column.

Comment: @RogerWolf, I can change the schema if needed.  I can change the primary key if needed, to speed up the select statement.  The ID column is just to make the table consistent with my other tables that do have an identity column.  I don't really search on the ID column.

Comment: @ProgrammerJoe, great. Rewritten my answer.

Comment: Thanks @RogerWolf!  I noticed you added "order by r.IPIntegerStart desc;".  Because there is no overlap in IP ranges, only 1 row is ever returned.  So I guess the "order by ... desc" helps the query run faster?

Comment: @ProgrammerJoe, on second thought, I don't think the descending sort order is necessary. Yes, sorting helps SQL Server to improve `top`ped searches, but you can remove the `desc` part.

Answer (score 0):

An update to my testing results and probably the final answer.  I especially hope this is a benefit for @MartinSmith and @RogerWolf who gave me lots of help.  A big thank you to Martin Smith and Roger Wolf!

Please note there is no IP range overlap in my data.  Also, there were several million rows in my data.

I tested a bunch of variations of clustered index, non clustered index, etc, using Roger Wolf's approach.  For that approach, setting the IPIntegerStart column as the clustered index had the largest impact on performance.

I tested other variations as well, such as:

1) Making both the IPIntegerStart and IPIntegerEnd the clustered index. The performance was comparable to just making IPIntegerStart the clustered index.

2) Making IPIntegerStart and IPIntegerEnd a non-clustered index, but leaving the ID (identity) column as the clustered primary key. The performance was approximately 8 times slower than Roger Wolf's rewritten solution, most likely because IPIntegerStart was not the clustered index.

3) Making IPIntegerStart the clustered index and IPIntegerEnd the non-clustered index. Making IPIntegerEnd a non-clustered index did not have a significant impact on performance. Again, what mattered was that IPIntegerStart is set as the clustered index.

The moral of the story is, as I tinkered with different variations of setting the clustered and non-clustered index, what mattered the most in the end was that setting IPIntegerStart as the clustered index had the biggest impact to speed things up.

Now for Martin Smith's suggestion, as specified at [dba.stackexchange.com/a/14896/3690](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/14896/3690) (which was originally written by Jack Douglas):

4) The general idea of Jack Douglas's approach is that the table is partitioned into different segments (what Jack Douglas refers to as "granule" in his write up).  I split my table up into 4 segments instead of 3.  The more data your table stores, the more segments you can add if you want to speed up the lookup.  Note that the more segments you add, the more unions you do in the select statement - I'm not sure if the additional unions eventually add more overhead if you have too many segments.  Jack Douglas's approach yielded the fastest lookup, approximately 3 to 4 times faster than the basic approach of setting the IPIntegerStart as the clustered index.

So, here's the summary of 3 different approaches:

Approach 1) Using the ID (identity key) as the clustered index: Slowest approach

Approach 2) Roger Wolf's approach of setting the clustered index as IPIntegerStart, and setting IPIntegerEnd as the non-clustered index: Approximately 6 to 7 times faster than Approach 1)

Approach 3) Martin Smith's suggestion or Jack Douglas's approach of segmenting the table into "granules": About 3 to 4 times faster than Approach 2)